# How to redirect the user in app.post after authentication from MySQL database?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating a website, with a simple UI with user login/signup system with NodeJs and MySQL database. My authentication part is working, but am encountering trouble to redirect the user after the details have been verified. The form is using POST method and in the NodeJs file am authenticating the user in "app.post".

I have tried redirecting user using, "res.send", "res.redirect", "res.sendfie"
and all have failed. Am getting the Error: "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".

Login Form

```
<FORM autocomplete="on" action="http://localhost:8888/user" method="POST">
     <INPUT type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name">
     <INPUT type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
     <BUTTON class="button">Login</BUTTON>
</FORM>
```

NodeJs File

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mysql=require('mysql');

var con=mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database: "mydb"
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

con.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("connected");
});

function redirect(){
    res.send(__dirname + '/index.html');
}

app.get('/login.html',function(req,res){res.sendFile(__dirname+ "/" + "login.html");});
app.post('/user',function(req,res){
    var uname=req.body.username;
    var pass=req.body.pass;
  var sql="Select * from user where username = '"+uname+"' and pass='"+pass+"'";
    con.query(sql,function(err,result,fields){
        console.log(sql);
        console.log(result);
        if(err)
            throw err;
            else{
                if(result.length==1){
                    console.log("you have successfully logged in");
                    res.redirect("/dashboard.html");
                }
                else
            console.log("Sorry ! login failed");
            }
    });
  res.end();
});
con.end();

var server= app.listen(8888,function(){
    var host=server.address().address;
    var port=server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s%s",host,port);
});
```

I expect that after the data is authenticated, the user should be redirected to "dashboard.html" if the details are correct, else it should redirect at "error.html".

Answer (score 0):

add middleware

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/dashboard.html"));
```

in '/user'

```
if(result.length==1){
                console.log("you have successfully logged in");
                res.redirect("/dashboard");
            }
            else
        console.log("Sorry ! login failed");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues with your express `routes`. It's advisable not to use file type extension in your route like `login.html`, simply use `login`.

You've not defined `dashboard.html` route for `res.redirect("/dashboard.html")`

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile()__dirname + "/dashboard.html"
})
app.post('/user',function(req,res,next){
  var uname = req.body.username;
  var pass = req.body.pass;
  var sql = "Select * from user where username = '"+uname+"' and pass='"+pass+"'";
  con.query(sql,function(err,result,fields){
    console.log(sql);
    console.log(result);
    if(err)
      // pass error to error handler middleware
      // it's preferrable to handle error in express with the catch all error middleware
      next(err);
    else {
      if(result.length === 1){
        console.log("you have successfully logged in");
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
      } else {
        console.log("Sorry ! login failed");
      }
     }
  });
});
con.end();

// catch all error
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err);
})
```